# How can I make an AlertDialog with multiple items whose names are defined at runtime?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList) explains how to do it when you know the names for the items at compile time, but what if I want them defined at runtime... i.e. Today, Tomorrow, (Day and Date after Tomorrow), etc...

Comment: what's the difficulty? why can't you create array in run-time and fill it with desired items?

Comment: The items variable has to be declared as final. Am I missing something? Doesn't final mean that I can't change the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The items variable has to be declared as final.

No, it doesn't.

> Doesn't final mean that I can't change the value?

**For that specific example**, it is declared `final` because it is shown as being just a local variable, and the value is also needed inside the anonymous `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` inner class.

However:

1. Just because something is declared `final` does not mean it has to be a literal. For example, the `final` keyword is used on parameters to methods sometimes, and those clearly are not statically created. To quote [Wikipedia](http://goo.gl/ZBWZ), "A final variable can only be initialized once, either via an initializer or an assignment statement."
2. There are other places you can put your array other than a local variable that will not require the `final` keyword, if you do not wish to use `final`. One likely candidate would be a data member of your activity.

Comment: Ah. Great. Thanks for the help. I just read up some more on final, and realize that my understanding was way lacking. Coming from C++, I don't always realize when stuff is drastically different in java until after posting on here. Thanks again.

Comment: @segfault: Yeah, you'll run into the occasional terminology overlap there. I seem to recall running into that problem when I learned Java, back when dinosaurs roamed the Earth. Of course, I learned C++ years before that, from some well-organized amino acids in the primordial soup. (mmmmmmmmm... soup!) :-)